# How powerful is League of Assassins armor?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, arrow

In the season 3 finale,

> Oliver stopped Ra's sword with his own hand, then killed Ra's Al Ghul with his sword, then he is shot three times in the chest by the snipers, and survived without any injuries.

According to Nyssa, he should thank the League armor. I believe all members of the League probably wear the same armor.

Is it realistic that an armor can stop bullets but not a blade?

Comment: Even Kevlar armor, which provides decent ballistic protection usually won't do much against being stabbed with a sword (unless designed with strike plates).

Comment: I still haven't got a chance to go through season 3 of Arrow, but isn't Ras al Ghul able to restore himself even from death thanks to the Lazarus pit? Or is this Ras Al Ghul different from Batman's? If not then i think Nyssa was covering up for his use of the pit to survive the lethal attack of arrow.

Comment: @yondaime008 yes, he can, and we see the Lazarus Pit, but there's a reason Ra's does not do this.

Comment: It's not the League Armor he has to thank; it's the [plot armor](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlotArmor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's how Kevlar works. While the specifics of League armor hasn't been shown, in the real world, Kevlar jackets have two traits. One is ceramic or other force spreading material, that stop bullets (of x caliber at y distance, no jacket stops all bullets). The second is weaving wires to prevent slashing. It does this by tight wire mesh in line with the fabric. You can buy consumer gloves that are cut proof (and heat proof, yay kevlar). But this wire mesh doesn't stop piercing or stabbing, as the point of a weapon will slip between the weave of the wire mesh.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not that powerful at all.

In the season finale and the episode right before, we see the League members being dropped left, right and center from:

- Gunshot wounds by both pistol and some kind of rifle (Diggle).
- Katana (Tatsuo).
- Blunt sticks (Laurel).
- Electricity (Palmer).

But I guess that the piece Oliver had on is impervious to fall damage and sniper shots to the chest.

So there is no evidence to support that League armour in *Arrow* is in any kind better that cloth armour.

Oliver's is either special or we get an explanation in the next season.

Comment: to be fair, Oliver *is* special, he might have better Armor than the average league grunt.

Comment: Ye, like Daft said nothing beats plot armor.